# How can you write "10 to the power of X" ($10^X$) if you can only use standard text?

Tags: notation, exponentiation

Basically the title says it all: You have to fill in a form which only allows standard text in ASCII characters - how would you write $10^X$ then? It should be universally understandable and not be restricted to a certain group of experts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two standard ways are: 10^X and 10 ** X.  Either one of those should be almost universally recognized.

Comment: Both Google and WolframAlpha accepts both inputs, but uses ^ when writing back to you. $\TeX$ only recognises ^. So that's slightly in favour of ^.